# Sentry.io JavaScript tunnel on Laravel route?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sentry

**The issue:** 
Because of issues with the JavaScript code loading I am trying to integrate sentry with the tunnel option. This would prevent the blocking, if a user has an ad-blocker enabled.
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/troubleshooting/#using-the-tunnel-option

[image: example of the loading blocking, from sentry.io]

Now they provide an example code for this tunnel in their documentation:

```
<?php
// Change $host appropriately if you run your own Sentry instance.
$host = "sentry.io";
// Set $known_project_ids to an array with your Sentry project IDs which you
// want to accept through this proxy.
$known_project_ids = array(  );

$envelope = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
$pieces = explode("\n", $envelope, 2);
$header = json_decode($pieces[0], true);
if (isset($header["dsn"])) {
    $dsn = parse_url($header["dsn"]);
    $project_id = intval(trim($dsn["path"], "/"));
    if (in_array($project_id, $known_project_ids)) {
      $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-sentry-envelope\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $envelope
        )
      );
      echo file_get_contents(
          "https://$host/api/$project_id/envelope/",
          false,
          stream_context_create($options));
    }
}
```

In the `app.php`, the layout file of my project, I am calling the JavaScript Sentry like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/assets/js/app.js') }}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**My question:**
What I don't understand is how to integrate this into the web.php as a route. So it gets called everytime an JavaScript error occured.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define a route like this:

```
Route::post('/sentry-tunnel', function (Request $request) {
    // Change $host appropriately if you run your own Sentry instance.
    $host = "sentry.io";

    // Set $known_project_ids to an array with your Sentry project IDs which you
    // want to accept through this proxy.
    $known_project_ids = [];

    $envelope = $request->getContent();
    $pieces = explode("\n", $envelope, 2);
    $header = json_decode($pieces[0], true);

    if (isset($header['dsn'])) {
        $dsn = parse_url($header['dsn']);
        $project_id = intval(trim($dsn['path'], '/'));

        if (in_array($project_id, $known_project_ids)) {
            return Http::withBody($envelope, "application/x-sentry-envelope")
                ->post("https://$host/api/$project_id/envelope/");
        }
    }
});
```

And then call the URL '/sentry-tunnel' from your JavaScript. Don't forget to add your project ID and credentials if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. While this looks very promising I get this error: `app.js:1 
POST http://project.test/sentry-tunnel 419 (unknown status)` Do you have an idea what could cause this?

Comment: @NiftyMatrix you should make this URL skip the CSRF validation middleware. Depending on your Laravel version you should have a middleware file that does the CSRF validation on requests and you should add `/sentry-tunnel` to be ignored for this validation. Most likely its in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` in the `protected $except` property.

Comment: No, the route is not inside a middleware. It is completely standalone. That is why I cannot explain why it wont work.

Comment: @NiftyMatrix you can run `php artisan route:list` and see if there is a middle ware on this route.

Comment: there is no middleware on that route, if I run `php artisan route:list`.